# Merging multiple Worksheet_SelectionChange

Tags: excel, vba

I have got no problem in running one Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange , but when i add multiple Worksheet_SelectionChange events it is not running. Later, i came to know that it is not possible running different worksheet selection change events in the same sheet.

I am having four different Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange events, trying to merge them with the help of various sites but none worked to me, as per my understanding.
Could i get some help,
1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cells1 As Range
Set cells1 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B27")
If Not (Intersect(Target, cells1) Is Nothing) Then
   ActiveSheet.Range("B30").Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cells2 As Range
Set cells2 = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C27")
If Not (Intersect(Target, cells2) Is Nothing) Then
   ActiveSheet.Range("C30").Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

3.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cells3 As Range
Set cells3 = ActiveSheet.Range("S1:S27")
If Not (Intersect(Target, cells3) Is Nothing) Then
   ActiveSheet.Range("S30").Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

4.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cells4 As Range
Set cells4 = ActiveSheet.Range("T1:T27")
If Not (Intersect(Target, cells4) Is Nothing) Then
   ActiveSheet.Range("T30").Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a switch (`select case`) within your change event to allow options for which will occur.

Mock-up:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 27 then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 2, 3, 19, 20
            Cells(30,Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
    End Select
End Sub
```

I have added the `Exit Sub` check for if the row > 27, as your ranges are 1:27, for each of the Columns.  This replaces the `Intersect()` check.

You perform the same action based on the `Target.Column`, so that is the only other parameter to verify and utilize.

Comment: Surprisingly super :) Short and worked like a jiffy. Thank you.

Comment: @kopsy If this has resolved your issue, please mark as Answered (check mark to the left of the post), so it is marked appropriately in the question log.

Comment: Although, for a better understanding what if i wanted to have headers for these ranges? pushing the existing ranges 1 or 2 rows below?

Comment: @kopsy You could add a second check for the `Target.Row < 2 And Target.Row > 27 Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: I think you meant `Target.Row < 2 Or Target.Row > 27`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @BigBen